# How to restrict other domains calling web api, means i want to allow only one particular domain to call web api

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing one project in Web Api, I want to restrict other domains calling my web api, but only allow my domain name only.
How can I restrict that,
I'm waiting for your valuable answers

I added this code inside WebApiConfig

```
config.EnableCors();
```

and the following code on top of the controller

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:49873", headers: "accept,content-type,origin,x-my-header", methods: "*")]
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Dear Pablo, Thank you for your valuable response,
But the problem is, if I'm trying to call web api from ajax the cors is working fine. but if I'm trying to call web api from code behind c#, cors is not working. it is allowing 2 domains to access my web api. but I want to allow only one domain

Comment: Edwin, CORS applies only when a web app is consuming an API sitting on a different origin than the web app origin. If you're doing service 2 service comunication (server code attacking server code) then there's no CORS.

Comment: Pablo, is there any other way to restrict this issue. I'm waiting for your response.

Comment: So this is an authorization problem. You want to authorize certain services to access your endpoints while unauthorizing the rest of the world. Look into PSK authorization for aspnetcore

Comment: Pablo, I have one more doubt, how to get client domain url that is requesting for web api?